# glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer:

Tags: c++, linux, malloc

when i compiled(c++ program) in linux i am getting following error pls help me

```
glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer:0x0804878d ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0xbd5f18]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_free+0x79)[0xbd941d]
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0x3233fe1]
./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x100)[0x8048514]
./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x176)[0x804858a]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xdc)[0xb877e4]
./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x5d)[0x8048471]
======= Memory map: ========
00b55000-00b6e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6687029    /lib/ld-2.4.so
00b6e000-00b6f000 r-xp 00018000 fd:00 6687029    /lib/ld-2.4.so
00b6f000-00b70000 rwxp 00019000 fd:00 6687029    /lib/ld-2.4.so
00b72000-00c9e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 6687030    /lib/libc-2.4.so
00c9e000-00ca1000 r-xp 0012b000 fd:00 6687030    /lib/libc-2.4.so
00ca1000-00ca2000 rwxp 0012e000 fd:00 6687030    /lib/li
```

Comment: Isn't the pointer you're free()ing already free()'d ?

Comment: you free invalid pointer, if you want more information, you will have to provide some more information

Comment: You did something bad to the heap.  Maybe a debugging tool like valgrind can help you with more detail.

Comment: Enable debug symbols in your code.

Comment: enable debug symbols AND run your code inside valgrind...

Answer (score 3):

> glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer:0x0804878d ***

This means you probably`delete`d a pointer that hasn't been created with `new`.

If you want any useful help, you really should post the code that generates this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at these two lines of the stack trace, you will see that the page that starts at 0x8048000 must be executable (because two addresses within that page, 0x8048514 and 0x804858a appear as return addresses on the stack).

./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x100)[0x8048514]
./a.out(__gxx_personality_v0+0x176)[0x804858a]

The address you are trying to free, 0x0804878d, is at offset 0x78d in that same page so it probably points to code and definitely points within a page that is executable.